# IOS Swift calling function from a different class getting nil

Tags: swift, uitableview, swift3

I am using swift 3, I have a TableView that gets data from the database . When the TableView gets to the 3rd row to last then I get more data from the database . Everything works correctly however I have about 3 different TableViews that can use that functionality so I am isolating the logic and putting it into it's own function so I can call it for the 3 other Tableviews. This is my code that works correctly

```
class HomeC: UIViewController,UITableViewDataSource,UITableViewDelegate {

    var streamsModel = streamModel()
    var timeLineModel = TimeLineModel()

      func reloadTable() {
      // This gets data from the database 
        timeLine.Stream(streamsModel: streamsModel, TableSource: TableSource, Controller: self, post_preview: post_preview, model: timeLineModel)

    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

        if timeLineModel.Counter <= streamsModel.Locations.count {
            if indexPath.row == self.streamsModel.Locations.count - 3  {
                // I now get 20 more rows from the database
                timeLineModel.Page += 1
                reloadTable()
                timeLineModel.Counter += 20
            }
        } 
    }

 }
```

The code above works correctly however I have to use that same logic in the 3 other TableViews and I would like to get that logic into 1 function and then just call it . This is my new code

```
class TimeLine: NSObject {

        func GetMoreData(streamsModel: streamModel, timeLineModel: TimeLineModel, indexPath: IndexPath) {


            if timeLineModel.Counter <= streamsModel.Locations.count {
                if indexPath.row == streamsModel.Locations.count - 3  {

                    timeLineModel.Page += 1
                   // I Get a nil error here
                    HomeC().reloadTable()
                    timeLineModel.Counter += 20
                }
            }
        }
      }

    then I call it here

     class HomeC: UIViewController,UITableViewDataSource,UITableViewDelegate {
 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

        timeLine.GetMoreData(streamsModel: streamsModel, timeLineModel: timeLineModel, indexPath: indexPath)

    }
}
```

I get the nil error on **HomeC().reloadTable()** which is understandable is there anyways I can fix this ? The error only occurs when I try to get more data because **the new function can not see that the reloadTable function and everything inside of it has already been initialized in the HomeC Class/Controller**.

Comment: The instance returned from `HomeC()` is not the instance in the storyboard. You need the actual reference by outlet, protocol/delegate, callback closure or notification.

Comment: Oh ok I will look into that now, I am trying to do that without calling the ViewDidLoad method a 2nd time .

Comment: You should create a separate DataSource Manager class where UITableViewDataSource delegate is implemented with all logic at single place.

Comment: And you can then just assign this datasource to different VCs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like bad design. When you directly call `reloadTable()` from another object, it increases complexity of your code. Other objects shouldn't know about internal implementation of controller. You can add `complete` block to `getMoreData` (names of methods start with lowercase letter) signature. This block will call instead of `HomeC().reloadTable()`

```
func getMoreData(streamsModel: streamModel, 
                               timeLineModel: TimeLineModel, 
                               indexPath: IndexPath, 
                               complete: @escaping  () -> Void) {
            if timeLineModel.Counter <= streamsModel.Locations.count {
                if indexPath.row == streamsModel.Locations.count - 3  {
                    timeLineModel.Page += 1
                    timeLineModel.Counter += 20
                    complete()
                }
            }
        }
 }
```

Using:

```
 timeLine.GetMoreData(streamsModel: streamsModel, 
                      timeLineModel: timeLineModel, 
                      indexPath: indexPath, 
                      complete:  { reloadTable() })
```

Comment: Yes I will make changes to the design and Thanks for example above worked perfectly.